# RMarkdown: table compiles in one file but not in another (\caption outside float)

Tags: r-markdown, knitr, kableextra

I am trying to include the same table into two different .Rmd files. It works in the first (a dissertation file), but not in the second (a "plos_article" file).

Here's the code for my table within the .Rmd file:

````
\begin{table}[tb]
\centering
\caption{Sociodemographic and questionnaire data of participants in the real-life and the laboratory group} 
\label{tab_study2participants}
```{r kable}
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
library(magrittr)
names(tab2) <- c("","Range","$\\textit{M}$","$\\textit{SD}$","Range","$\\textit{M}$","$\\textit{SD}$","Group comparison")
kable(tab2, "latex", booktabs = T, escape = FALSE) %>% 
  kable_styling(latex_options =c("striped","scale_down")) %>%
  add_header_above(c(" ", "Real-Life" = 3, "Laboratory" = 3))
```
\end{table}
````

In the "plos_article"-file, I get the following error:

"! Package caption Error: \caption outside float."

If I exclude the caption, I get:

"! LaTeX Error: Unknown float option `H'."

So I tried to include "\usepackage{float}" in the created .tex-file and then compiled it using MikTeX and pdfLaTeX. I got this error when run with the caption:

"l.218 \caption {Sociodemographic and questionnaire data of participants.}"

and this error when run without the caption:

"! Undefined control sequence.
 ...}{llllllll} \hiderowcolors \toprule "

When running with XeLaTeX instead, I got: 
"l.30 ...bleLigatures[f]{encoding = *, family = * }"

So, I'm pretty stuck. Might there be something obvious that I missed, being a beginner to RMarkdown? Since my table compiles perfectly in the first project, this is kind of what I expect.

Comment: Does the file that fails have `\usepackage{booktabs}` in the `.tex` file it produces?  Your errors look like it is not being used.

Comment: Indeed, the generated .tex file did not have \usepackage{booktabs} in it. Including in manually did not resolve the problem, however: Compiling the file in MiKTeX produced the same error. Do I have to place the command in a specific place maybe?

Comment: Yes, it needs to be in the header before the first use of any macro in it.

Comment: It worked, but only if I included both \usepackage{booktabs} and 
\usepackage{float} in the header.

Comment: I've found out multiple times that also deleting the .tex file and the log file generated usually help to solve the issue.